# AWS Amplify graphql client IAM setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using the [Amplify graphql client](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#amplify-graphql-client) in my project. After custom auth I have the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.
I need to provide these to the Amplify configuration but I can find no documentation whatsoever about it. The closest documentation I've seen is :

```
const myAppConfig = {
    // ...
    'aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint': 'https://xxxxxx.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql',
    'aws_appsync_region': 'us-east-1',
    'aws_appsync_authenticationType': 'AWS_IAM',
    // ...
}

Amplify.configure(myAppConfig);
```

But it does not specify where should the credentials be entered.
They are specified for the AWS Appsync SDK but not the graphql client.

Any assistance or insights are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using AWS.config

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials(your credentials here)
```

Amplify.configure then works fine